# Is there an orthodox way to develop Android TV apps

Tags: android-tv

I have a few problems with understanding of android tv development. First of all when i had launched android tv project and was trying to create custom interface for new activity, unfortunately i couldn't find any xml elements which could help me. From the example i got some ideas that whole interface provided by android SDK collected in many fragments. I just can modify colors, fonts, fonts size, transparency maybe animation and etc. But if i really need to customize structure of controls and WTF i wanna output "Hello World" inside label!!! Is it possible? I read all articles from this link https://developer.android.com/training/tv/index.html but it is still useless for me (maybe I am unique :) ). After this suffering with google guide, i have done a conclusion that the platform so new and there is no way to do some thing except only way that was provided by google. Am i right? If not, what should i do to find successful way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragments provided by Google as part of the "leanback" framework are templates designed to make it easy for content providers to start publishing to Android TV without having to worry about the technical details of building a TV UI.  The idea is that a content provider can create a channel just by feeding in their video content.  This ease of use comes at a cost, customization is difficult or impossible with these templates.

However there is nothing preventing you from creating your own Activities and Fragments from scratch and implementing a completely custom UI for the TV, it works just like any other Android device.  Add "android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" to your manifest and see for yourself.